# How I can build a .jar file first and then my andoid app?

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar

In my project: https://github.com/pc-magas/sercommH300sVoipCredentialsRecovery source is seperated into 2 parts:

1. The core library where no android dependencies are placed.
2. The android app iself.

Core Logic is in `app/src/main/java/pc_magas/vodafone_fu_h300s/logic/` and the tests for the core logic is in: `app/src/test/java/pc_magas/vodafone_fu_h300s/logic/`

Therefore, I want to split my build process into these phases:

1. Build a .jar out of the `app/src/main/java/pc_magas/vodafone_fu_h300s/logic/`
2. place it into `./app/libs`
3. Build the app itself using the generated .jar

Therefore how I can configure the `gradle.build` to build my library first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well based upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67368367/4706711) you'll need you create a new Java/Kotlin library in order to do this you'll need to follow these steps:

1. In android studio select File -> New -> New Module
2. Then select Java or Kotlin Library.
3. Use the default settings.

This step creates a new folder with its own `build.gradle`. I'll assume that the folder's name is `settings_fetcher`. The folder name is the one you choose in this window:

[image: Android Studio window that decides the folder library name as well]

Also, this name mentioned above is the name you'll need to place into the application's dependency as well. So in the window shown above used `settings_fetcher` as Library Name then you'll need to place the following dependency into your `build.gradle` located into

Once you created the module place into `app/build.gradle` the correct dependency as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67368367/4706711).

Then move the files located in `app/src/main/java/pc_magas/vodafone_fu_h300s/logic/` into the `settings_fetcher/src/main/java/pc_magas/vodafone_fu_h300s/logic/` also move any tests, related to the library, located in `app/src/tests` into `settings_fetcher/src/tests` (Assuming the new library is named `settings_fetcher`)

Then try to run the tests and build the application as well in order to ensure the correctness of the application's functionality as well.