# How I can build java module first then the rest of my android application?

Tags: java, android, gradle

In my java project I have the following folders:

- `app` that contains the android specific application
- `settings_fetcher` that is a java module

What I want to do is to build first the java modult create a `.jar` file then movwe the `.jar` file into `./app/libs` and then build the rest of the application.

The `app` folder contains the following `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

def versionCodeDate() {
    return new Date().format("yyyyMMdd").toInteger()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pcmagas.vodafone_fu_h300s"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode versionCodeDate()
        versionName "v"+versionCodeDate()

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            println 'In release configs'
            def keystoreFile = rootProject.file(".keys/h300s.keystore")
            def env = System.getenv();

            if(env.containsKey('KEYSTORE_FILE')){
                keystoreFile = rootProject.file(env.get('KEYSTORE_FILE'))
            }

            if (keystoreFile.exists() ) {
                println("Configuring Signing options for release")

                android.signingConfigs["release"].storeFile = keystoreFile
                android.signingConfigs["release"].storePassword = System.getenv('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD')
                android.signingConfigs["release"].keyAlias = System.getenv('KEYALIAS')
                android.signingConfigs["release"].keyPassword = System.getenv('MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD')
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig =  signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20210307'

    testImplementation 'com.github.gmazzo:okhttp-mock:1.4.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.+'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Whilst `settings_fetcher` contains the following `build_gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}


task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/libs/')
    into('../app/libs/')
    include('settings_fetcher.jar')
}
```

Any ideas on how I can approach this?

In other words, what I want to do is when I run one of these commands:

- `gradlew assemble^flavor^`
- `gradlew build`
- `gradlew build^flavor^`

Where `^flavor^` is my application's flavor and can be either `Debug` or `Release`.

To be able to build the `.jar` file first and then my app's apk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the `settings_fetcher` is a dependency to your `app` assuming that the `settings_fetcher` is created as `java-library` then you can do the following:

In the `build.gradle` located in `app` folder place the `settings_fetcher` project as dependency:

```
// rest of build.gradle goes here
dependencies{
  // Your app's dependencies goes here
  implementation project(":settings_fetcher")
}
```

So once you run `./gradlew build` the jar file for your library will be located upon `./settings_fetcher/build/libs` folder. Therefore, there's no need for `makeJar` task as well.

### Library Dependencies

Also, any library dependencies should be placed in its own respective `build.gradle`  in your case the one located in `settings_fetcher` folder in a `dependencies` section.

For example if your library needs the `okHttp` client then use:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
}
```

Also in order to use 3rd party libraries ensure that you also have the appropriate repositories as well for example a common repository is the `jcenter` one:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

### Final build.gradle located in `settings_fetcher` folder

As a result, the final `build.gradle` will be this one if no extra libraries needed:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Or in case you will need some extra dependencies & libraries:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

dependencies {
  // App dependencies go here.
}
```